# Getting incorrect json response in ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I need to send large byte array as response from REST service to ajax request. I'm creating list as:

```
List<List<Byte>> list = new List<List<byte>>();
```

here, the inner list will have 1000 bytes each. This is the code:

```
int cnt = 0;
List<Byte> innerList = new List<Byte>();

for (int i = 0; i < fileBytes.Length; i++)
{
    if (cnt < 1000)
    {
        Byte b = fileBytes[i];
        innerList.Add(b);
        cnt++;
        if (i == fileBytes.Length - 1)
        {
            list.Add(innerList);
                        log.Debug("Remaining:");
                        log.Debug("List: " + list.Count);
                        log.Debug("innerList: " + innerList.Count);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(innerList);
                log.Debug("Remaining:");
                log.Debug("List: " + list.Count);
                log.Debug("innerList: " + innerList.Count);
        innerList.Clear();
        cnt = 0;
    }
}

return list;
```

Now, according to `log`, I have total count of`list` as 503, with first 502 having 1000 count each(this will be `innerList`) & in 503'th, child list contains `54` bytes.

This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType: "jsonp", 
                data: dd,
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonp: "callback",
                url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/MyWebService/WebService.svc/MyMethod",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                complete: function (request, textStatus) { //for additional info
                    alert(request.responseText);
                    alert(textStatus);
                },
                error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                  }
            });
```

The request gets completed successfully, but in `firebug` I noticed that, I get `data` in `success` as collection of `503` jsons each having `54`(!) keys. I think I was supposed to get `1000` keys in first `502` jsons in the `data` & only in the 503'th I sould get 54 keys. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use the same instance of `innerList`  which is 54 bytes long at the end. Try to create new instances.

Eg, instead of `innerList.Clear();`, try `innerList = new List<Byte>();`

---

EDIT

Since you pass the file content as json, i guess performance is not your main concern.
If so, you can use the below Linq (with side effects), which is shorter and less error-prone

```
int cnt = 0;
List<List<byte>> chunks = fileBytes
                            .GroupBy(x => cnt++ / 1000)
                            .Select(x => x.ToList())
                            .ToList();
```